# JSON.Net Parse Custom Mapped JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

Have been struggling with this one for a while now.

I have JSON in the following format:

```
[
{
    "Q_LabelOne": {
        "en": "Some English text",
        "fr": "Some French"
    }
},
{
    "Q_LabelTwo": {
        "en": "Some English text",
        "fr": "Some French"
    }
}
]
```

And then I have models like so:

```
public class Resource
{
    public string Label { get; set; } // where Label is basically "Q_LabelOne"
    public string ValueEN { get; set; }
    public string ValueFR { get; set; }
}
```

How would I parse this JSON in such format?

Comment: If you have a chance to modify class Resource would be pretty fine for better operation.

Comment: Can you modify your JSON? An array of hashmap looks weird. You might be better off having a hashmap with the Keys being your 'Label' and the Values being your Resource object (En, Fr).

Comment: I need that label to be readable as it is a resource used by a person in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Resource class to the following to just have the values mapped using JSON.NET attributes. Then parse the JSON to a `List<Dictionary<string, Resource>>` with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, Resource>>>(jsonString)`. This will give you a List of single item Dictionaries with a key of "Q_LabelOne" and "Q_LabelTwo" and a value of their respective `Resource`.

```
public class Resource
{

    [JsonProperty("en")]
    public string ValueEn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fr")]
    public string ValueFr { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this does the job as well, because I can use dictionary key later on when I actually map it to my models. This works for me ;) Although, I should have thought about that myself :D